# How to display the user name that delivered (TFS Check-in) the line of code in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I work with a team of developers on a shared WPF solution on TFS.

Is there a way to display above the lines of code the name of the user who delivered them on TFS?

Answer (score 1):

Not above the line, but from Visual Studio, if you right click in the file, select "Source Control" and then "Annotate" for TFVC or "Blame" for Git you should be able to see a breakdown on line level who committed the code.